# Data in excel being copied into a gmail note

Tags: microsoft-excel, gmail

Up until last week, I was able to copy and paste data from an excel spreadsheet into a gmail email and the text would come in as rich text, keeping the formatting and the hot links active. Now when I copy and paste, the data comes in as a table and the email addresses contained in the cells of the spreadsheet are no longer "hot". How can I fix this so the email addresses retain their hyperlink.

Comment: What version excel, what browser? What OS?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I tired everything I knew to get around this issue. The only way I can make it work like before is to log in to gmail using Internet explorer. I know this is not a fix be a work around.
Dale